# JSON or AJAX REQUEST not shown in console when open page in new tab

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to open link in new tab using `target="_blank"`, for some reason its not working.

**link.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="somejs.js"></script>
```

**somejs.js**

```
 function loadFunction() {
    $.getJSON("data.php", function (data) {
        info = data.info;
        console.log(info);
    });
 }
 loadFunction();
```

As you see, somejs.js contains JSON script. 
When `link.php`'s page is loaded in a new tab, the JSON REQUEST is not shown in the console. However if I refresh the page first then the REQUEST is shown in console. JSON REQUEST is also available when I try to open the page in a new tab manually.

What is the matter?

here is the screenshot

**direct link or refresh**

[image: refresh]

**new tab**

[image: newtab]

Comment: There's nothing in the script that displays the result, it just assigns it to a variable.

Comment: the result is shown, but the json response is not showing. i'm wondering, why the script is not showing the json response in console. @Barmar

Comment: @William Chandra, I changed a lot of things in your question, please reject if it got deviated from what you were trying to ask

Comment: @WilliamChandra Why should it show the JSON response in the console? You have no `console.log()` statement.

Comment: Add `console.log(periode);` after `periode = data.info`

Comment: you can check it first when you first time load the page, at firebug, it will get JSON response, although i am not not using `console.log()`. @Barmar

Comment: I don't understand the question. If it gets the JSON response, what's the problem? Where is it supposed to be shown in the console?

Comment: all variable and all function works, but i just wondered to know that why the JSON response is not showing. the response that I meant was like `GET http://www.test.com/data.php (200 OK 52ms)` @Barmar

Comment: There's nothing in your script that shows the JSON response. Where are you expecting to see it?

Comment: it is useless when i used `console.log(periode)` it just show the periode value, and something like `GET http://www.test.com/data.php (200 OK 52ms)` is not shown. @Barmar

Comment: `GET http://www.test.com/data.php` is the request, not the response.

Comment: have you tried to run my script? you could see the differences when you are using new tab or without new tab to load the page. @Barmar

Comment: okay I was just wrong to tell you what I meant, so is there any solution to show the JSON request? @Barmar

Comment: Are you asking why you don't see the AJAX request in the Network tab when you open Developer Tools in the new window? It doesn't show any AJAX requests that occurred before you first go to the Network tab. Going to that tab is what tells it to start recording network requests.

Comment: if you are trying to get the URL of the request in the success function, use `this.url` in the function, that _should_ work. Can't test it right now to be 100%. Otherwise, I'm just as confused as Barmar.

Comment: i have  tried to call the function using `setInterval(loadFunction,5000)`, but it only show the output that i `console.log()` every 5 seconds and  the request is still not shown. @Barmar

Comment: Did you open the Network tab while it's running?

Comment: in network tab, it shown the request. @Barmar

Comment: What else are you expecting? AJAX requests aren't shown anywhere else in the console.

Comment: I suspect I'm just not understanding what you're looking for. You say it works when you refresh the page. Can you post a screenshot of what you get when it works correctly?

Comment: i've uploaded the screenshot to the question. please check. @Barmar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131024/discussion-between-barmar-and-william-chandra).

Answer (score 2):

From the comments I believe there is a confusion of terms. When you mention you don't see the request in the console I believe you mean the Network debugger.

The console is something different, and that is why other users told you to use `console.log()` if you want anything to be seen on the Javascript console.

What you are experiencing is something particular of the browser. If you have the Debugger/Inspector open before loading the page the Network tab should show any request done via AJaX. If it doesn't then it is some technicality on the browser side that prevents from showing it, but the call is done (as you can test by `console.log()`).

> When link.php's page is loaded in a new tab, the JSON REQUEST is not
>   shown in the console.
>
> JSON REQUEST is also available when I try
>   to open the page in a new tab manually.

From these two comments I deduce the only case when you don't see the call on the Network tab is when you have page A with a link that opens `link.php` on a new tab.

If that's the case then that's because the debugger you are looking at belongs to page A. You then open a new tab, which does not have the debugger open yet, and any request done from `link.php` does not have any place to be shown at.

If you refresh `link.php` with its own debugger panel open, then you do see the request. And the same if you call `link.php` manually in a new tab which already has the debugger open.